# How to fetch data from database after 2 seconds on a jsp page

Tags: jsp, web

Currently I'm working on a college web project. My application/web page is sports application/web page, so I wanted to fetch fresh score from database or an external API after every 2 seconds on my `jsp` page so please provide me a solution in which I do not have to refresh my page (*if it is possible*) and fetch latest score.

I'm really not getting what to do. Please help me out.

Comment: javascript timer that fires an ajax call to another servlet or jsp page

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 function getScore(){

    $.ajax(
    {
    url: "/yourUrl/score.jsp",  
    type:'POST',
    data: "input data",
    contentType: "application/json", //here specify content type
    success: function(result){
        alert(result); // here result is response return from score.jsp
          })


    },
    error: function(e) {
         alert("error in getting  score!");
            }
    });
    setTimeout(getScore, 2000);
}
```

here

setTimeout(getScore, 2000);

'setTimeout' is a java Script method that call getScore method on every 2000 m seconds.
in getScore call a ajax method that request for data on a particular servlet or jsp and get Data in response.